# my counter number animation not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, counter

I created the counter number feature with a random number, using `Math.random()`. I have made the code like below, but there are still things that are not working well. I have several numbers like `200` `1.9` and `1500`. The problem is, when other numbers the animation runs, but in number `1.9` the animation doesn't work. And also, can the speed be slowed down more?

Where are the missing or errors in the code that I created?

```js
// function for count statistic
function countNumber() {

$('.count').each(function() {

var countTo = Number($(this).text())

$(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
     Counter: countTo - 1
}, {
     duration: 2000,
     easing: 'swing',
     step: function(now) {
     var ceil = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(now))
         if (ceil < countTo) {
         $(this).text(ceil);
     }
     },
     complete: function() {
         $(this).text(countTo);
     }
  });
 });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  countNumber();
});
```

```css
#countAnimation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom:200px;
}

.box-counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="countAnimation">
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1.9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: becaus 2000 is more than 1.9 so if (ceil < countTo) equals to false

Comment: Then, how? can you give me an example from the code that i've made? @nAviD

Comment: fist you tell how do you want to count to 1.9 ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you have set each animation from `0` to `countTo - 1`. For `1.9`, this means that it will be slowly transitioning from `0` to `0.9` and on each step, you multiply a random number by a floored number between `0` and `0.9`:

`var ceil = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(now))`

which will always be `0`. You then set this 0 to be the value of the text if it is lower(which it always will be because it's always 0).

```
if (ceil < countTo) {
  $(this).text(ceil);
}
```

Your best best is probably to not floor `now` when you set the `ceil` variable.

If you're concerned about having a ton of extra digits in your resulting number, perhaps try using .toFixed() after your if condition:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Change your step function to this:

```
 step: function(now) {
   
     var ceil = Math.random() * now;

     if (ceil < countTo) {
        ceil = ceil.toFixed(1);
        $(this).text(ceil);
     }
 },
```

Comment: then, how should it be? from the code that I've made above

Comment: if i use ```toFixed``` as you suggest, the number still ```0,0``` not counting

Comment: I made changes to my answer to show the change to your step function

Answer (score 0):

The code is working properly. First you can change the counter speed by changing {duration: 5000,} this, each 1000 is 1 second. Second, The 1.9 value can not animate in equal speed with 1500. That's why it runs when the animation is almost done. Try changing the value to a bigger number.
Let me know if this solves your issue.

```js
// function for count statistic
function countNumber() {

$('.count').each(function() {

var countTo = Number($(this).text())

$(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
     Counter: countTo - 1
}, {
     duration: 5000,
     easing: 'swing',
     step: function(now) {
     var ceil = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(now))
         if (ceil < countTo) {
         $(this).text(ceil);
     }
     },
     complete: function() {
         $(this).text(countTo);
     }
  });
 });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  countNumber();
});
```

```css
#countAnimation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom:200px;
}

.box-counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="countAnimation">
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1.9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: however, the number I want is 1.9. Because it is my client's want. 1.9k

Comment: then instead of using 1.9k why not use the actual number. 1900?